# Ethernet switch does not always start working

Tags: ethernet, switch

I have a router with 4 ethernet ports. Since I need more ports I use an ethernet switch to multiply the ports. In my current setup 3 ethernet ports of the router are used by 3 computers, the remaining port goes to an ethernet switch and two other ports of the switch are used by additional 2 computers.

The ethernet switch is tp/link 5 port 10/100 Mbps device.

In order to run this system I'm doing various trial and error experiments such as turn-on/off router/switch, plug in/out ethernet cables, etc. The thing is the 2 computers connected to the ethernet switch sometimes get connected to the Internet (once they are connected there are no further problems). But the problem is when I turn off the switch and turn it on again the Internet connections of these 2 computers connected to the switch get lost then I need to do those trial and error experiments again to make the system to work.

What is the problem here? Is there a sequence of steps which will make the system work without doing these trial and error experiments? Thanks

Comment: Just the internet connection or also the LAN connection? Do the 2 computers at least get an IP address from your router, when you turn on the switch? Do they get an IP address from the _correct_ router? (Does the gateway's MAC address in `arp -a` look right?)

Answer (score 0):

That is a fairly slow switch. My experience with these older devices is that they stop working at random intervals and need to be restarted. Fairly common.

Replace it it with a newer, faster switch that is good to top quality and the problems should disappear.